# Verify File Size

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm currently working on a program that downloads files from my server once a button is clicked, and then verifies that once the file is the specified size (One is 56,450 KB), then once it verifies the file is 56,450 KB, it copies the file from the folder it was downloaded into, and puts it in a different folder. Is is possible to get VB.NET to verify a file is a certain size?

```
If "C:\UpdateFiles\AfterFXLib.dll" >= '56,540 Then
    'Copy file to "C:\Folder\"
End If

downloader = New System.Net.WebClient()

downloader.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://*******/PatchFiles/AfterFXLib.dll"), "C:\UpdateFiles\AfterFXLib.dll")

My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\UpdateFiles\AfterFXLib.dll")

If "C:\UpdateFiles\AfterFXLib.dll" >= '56,540 Then

End If
```

I'm hoping I can get VB.net to verify the file is a certain size before copying the file.

Comment: (In the text it says "56,450" but in the comment in the code it says "56,540".)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Dim myFile As New FileInfo("C:\UpdateFiles\AfterFXLib.dll")
Dim sizeInBytes As Long = myFile.Length
Dim sizeInKB =  sizeInBytes / 1024

If sizeInKB  >= 56540 Then
    ' do your stuff
End If
```

Should be explicit enough